# Eslint issue on Yarn Install

Tags: node.js, eslint, nvm, eslintrc

I am trying to run a project which requires 20.9.0. After installing the required node from NVM. Installation of yarn is giving the following error.

`npm install yarn`

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: optimism@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint@8.57.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"^8.57.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^7.12.1" from eslint-config-standard@16.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-config-standard
npm ERR!   dev eslint-config-standard@"^16.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
```

Here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "optimism",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Optimism PBC",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16",
    "pnpm": ">=8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx only-allow yarn"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.2",
    "@changesets/changelog-github": "^0.4.8",
    "@types/chai": "^4.3.8",
    "@types/chai-as-promised": "^7.1.4",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.9.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.10",
    "depcheck": "^1.4.7",
    "doctoc": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^35.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "^1.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^48.0.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "15.0.2",
    "markdownlint": "^0.31.0",
    "markdownlint-cli2": "0.4.0",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "nx": "17.0.2",
    "nx-cloud": "^16.0.4",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.0",
    "prettier-plugin-solidity": "^1.0.0-beta.13",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.5",
    "ts-mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@changesets/cli": "^2.26.0",
    "@codechecks/client": "^0.0.50",
    "yarn": "^1.22.22"
  }
}
```

I tried the following.

- Reinstalling NVM and Node
- Tried to install latest eslint

Even tried for setting up the eslint configuration but nothing is getting solved.

Comment: `npm install eslint-config-standard@17` - someone misconfigured a project probably

Comment: Not able to install, Could not resolve dependency peer eslint@"^7.0.0" from eslint-plugin-promise@5.2.0